# How do I use the apple-app-site-association file with a component parameter exact match?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I'm attempting to write a component match where I only match on a parameter of quesid=2109061920 of a URL within the apple-app-site-association file.  I want all this filtering done in the apple-app-site-association file and not in the swift mobile codebase.

Test URL:
https://example.org/MyChart/inside.asp?mode=questionnaire&from=list&src=sys&srcid=1&quesid=2109061920&empPIN=xxxxx%3D%3D&mobile=1

This somewhat works meaning it does filter only items with quesid but I can put anything after it like quesid=2109061920**777**... so it's not an exact match

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "***.com.***"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "?": {
              "quesid": "2109061920"
            },
            "comment": "testing"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This also didn't work:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "***.com.***"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/MyChart/*",
            "?": "quesid=2109061920",
            "comment": "testing"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *json* file to matching exact query parameter like below:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "***.com.***"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/MyChart/*",
            "?": { "quesid": "2109061920" },
            "comment": "testing"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will try this syntax.

Comment: This is not working in my case, I want to only enable when the query parameter is enabled, but it always show the button even if we have other url related to /MyChart/*.